# how to set an option selected by default through "selected" in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-forms

I had used the following code to display a drop-down. I wanted the inactive to be selected by default. I was able to achieve it through two way binding but is there any way that it could be achieved by only modifying the HTML?

```html
  
  <md-select id="status" name="status" class="form-  group"placeholder="Status" 
      formControlName="status">
    <md-option [value]="true">Active</md-option>
    <md-option  [value]="false" selected='true' >Inactive</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an angular material application open in front of me right now, but I'm thinking you could try with a template variable like so:

```
<md-select id="status" name="status" class="form-  
      group"placeholder="Status" 
      formControlName="status"
      (ngModel)="inactive.value">
    <md-option [value]="true">Active</md-option>
    <md-option #inactive  [value]="false" >Inactive</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: @AtulStha pls try the same code with  [(ngModel)] instead of  (ngModel)